# Hibernate tables from pojo classes

Tags: hibernate, pojo

I wonder if anybody can help.

I have a class structure that I am working on and I would like to generate the sql tables and mapping files from these classes.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.
You need:

1. hibernate.cfg.xml with this line

   create
   More info here: [Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-question-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)
   and here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html
2. you need to map the class: there are 2 ways:
   with annotation or hbm files. Here some about mapping: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html
   .

In the mapping you need to describe name table, catalog and (if you want) column.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. Hibernate does not contains such a tool. It is also not that straight forward operation, because tool would not have needed information. For example with following class, there is no way to figure out should `field1` or `field2` to be primary key, or should table perhaps have composite key:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int field1;
    private int field2;        
...
}
```